# Is possible to represent Date time in float format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

Basically I am working with two languages, one is ruby and the other is javascript.
In ruby you can do something like:

```
date.to_f
```

--> and gives you the float representation of the date, like this:

1541393269.3742561

But when you say in javascript:

```
Date.now()
```

1542377024455

I also tried with moment js, but still not entirely sure of how to reflect this float representation of time.

Is there a way to represent a Date in javascript with a float number like in ruby?

Comment: What’s wrong with `Date.now()/1000`? Or is your question about  how to get a higher accuracy then milliseconds?

Comment: To keep compatibility with legacy code

Comment: @t.niese did you saw that the ruby representation has 17 digits long in float? and that Date.now() is just 13 digits long?

Comment: I guess you just divide by 1000.  `Date.now()` is just the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

Comment: @juangarcia You can't add more precision to what is provided by JS.

Comment: @Amy well thats the question, for instance in nodejs you can work with performance precision, the same with the browser... may be there is a way... but I don't know

Comment: @juangarcia that’s why I asked if your question is about accuracy. Ruby displays the date in seconds since Unix epoche in microseconds accuracy and `Date.now` returns the date in milliseconds since Unix epoche in milliseconds accuracy. So with `Date.now()/1000` you have it in the same scale as with `to_f`. And floating points do not have digits they have an (most of the time) approximated value.

Comment: @juangarcia do you really need this high accuracy (In most cases microseconds are sufficient)? Or why are you concerned about those _missing 4 "digits"_?

Comment: @t.niese this same date is going to be parsed by ruby developers and I need to preserve compatibility in terms of data... I cannot remove just 4 digits because it is in the same "scale" I need it to be the same information scale with the correct information.

Comment: @juangarcia but if that time for some reason actually is `1542381284.2980000` then it would be logged or be written as `1542381284.298`, so if it is about the visual representation / parsing, and the interface relays on `7` digits to be present while reading it, then you have to use `toFixed(7)`, so you write `(Date.now()/1000).toFixed(7)` to get a String base representation of the number that is guaranteed to have 7 digits. Even with the `to_f` function in [answer of Patrick Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53340272/1960455)

Comment: @t.niese May be I can state it in a different way, I am working with nodejs I save a registry in a Database with 1542381284.2980000 while it should be 1542381284.2981234 when the ruby developer tries to parse this information I cannot be sure he would parse it correctly just because of the lost of this digits, I want it to be exactly the same values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance), you can get a higher precision than `Date.now()`, though to mitigate Spectre, some browsers arbitrarily restrict precision of this API so be careful if you really do need precise values:

```js
const to_f = () => (performance.timeOrigin + performance.now()) / 1000;
console.log(to_f());
```

Comment: This is correct I see that for nodejs it should be https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_now

Comment: Yes it looks like it works like this: ```performance.now() + performance.timeOrigin``` though I would probably move the dot there, is it safe to construct the date time like this? I always used moment for a reason...

Comment: "*… is it safe to construct the date time like this?*". If you trust the implementation to be compliant with the [language specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date) (and I don't think there has ever been, or ever will be, one that isn't in this regard), then yes.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript internally uses milliseconds since the epoch.

Although I'm not familiar with Ruby it looks like `date.to_f` gives a number in seconds since the epoch and you'll have to multiply this number by 1,000 to be compatible with JavaScript's Date.

```js
var rubyTime = 1541393269.3742561;
var jsTime = 1542377024455;

console.log(new Date(rubyTime * 1000));
console.log(new Date(jsTime));
```

Given that we know understand the relationship between the values to convert a JavaScript timestamp to a float, just divide by 1,000.

```
1542377024455 / 1000 => 1542377024.455
```

Unfortunately though JavaScript just doesn't have the same precision so the closest you can get is to 1 millisecond (10<sup>-3</sup> seconds) but Ruby has appears to have precision down to 1 microsecond (10<sup>-6</sup>) seconds.

Comment: Take a look one more time, and see how many digits you have in each number... that is the problem...

Comment: See [t.niese's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53340088/is-possible-to-represent-date-time-in-float-format/53340272?noredirect=1#comment93559501_53340088). OP already stated in their question that they were aware of this relationship. The problem isn't the scale of 1000, the problem is the millisecond-quantized values that `Date.now()` provides, while in Ruby it's quantized to microseconds.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts True, but not all browsers support `timeOrigin` method according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance#Browser_compatibility)